# In highcharts, the data in the legend is overlapping incase of data less than 10000

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts, frontend

When the user hovers on the map above the pointers shows tha data in the legend below it.If the data range is less than 10000 then it is overlapping as shown in the below image.Please suggest me how to format for the data below 10000( for data above 1000 the range is showing like 10k,12,5k etc.)[image]

Comment: try playing around with some styling options from here - http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend

Comment: can you show a live example or a fiddle?

Comment: Nothing i could find there.I have gone through that documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`colorAxis.labels.formatter`](http://api.highcharts.com/highmaps#colorAxis.labels.formatter) to accomplish a custom styling for the labels of the colorAxis used in your legend.

```
colorAxis: {
    labels : {
        formatter: function() {
    return parseInt(this.value) >= 1000 ? parseInt(this.value)/1000 + 'k' : this.value ;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have got a more modular answer for this one which i am posting below

Answer (score 1):

```
ColorAxis: {
   labels: {
                        formatter: function() {
                            var value = this.value.toFixed( 0 ),
                                newValue = value,
                                shortNum,
                                precision;
                            if ( 1000 <= value ) {
                                var suffixes = ['', 'K', 'M', 'B', 'T', 'G' ],
                                    suffixNum = Math.floor( ( '' + value ).length / 3 ),
                                    shortValue = '';
                                for ( precision = 2; precision >= 1; precision = precision - 1 ) {
                                    shortValue = parseFloat( ( 0 !== suffixNum ? ( value / Math.pow( 1000, suffixNum ) ) : value ).toPrecision( precision ) );
                                    var dotLessShortValue = ( shortValue + '' ).replace( /[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/g, '' );
                                    if ( dotLessShortValue.length <= 2 ) {
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                                if ( 0 !== shortValue % 1 ) {
                                    shortNum = shortValue.toFixed( 1 );
                                }
                                newValue = shortValue + suffixes[ suffixNum ];
                            }
                            return newValue;
                        }
                    }
}
```